# Share Value Across MVVM Model Hierarchy

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, hierarchical-data

I have an object hierarchy that is the model for a WPF application using the MVVM pattern.  Descendant objects need to be aware of a property that is set on the root object of the hierarchy.  The property can change from time-to-time (it's not just set when the hierarchy is created).  Before this requirement surfaced, there was no reason for a child to have a reference to it's parent or to the root object.

Simplified, abbreviated example:

```
public class Airplane
  public bool IsFlying { get; set}
  public ObservableCollection<WingAssembly> WingAssemblies { get; set; }

public class WingAssembly
  public void MethodNeedsIsFlyingState() { }
  public Flaps Flaps { get; set; }

public class Flaps
  public void MethodAlsoNeedsIsFlyingState() { }
```

Two patterns occur to me to solve this problem:

A) Add a parent (or root) object reference to children.

PRO's: Simple change, straightforward to reference root object's state

CON's: Creates a two-way object hierarchy that was not needed before... I'm not sure what downstream consequences I may run into (more complicated data model?)

B) Add an IsFlying property to descendant objects that require it.  Update descendant's state when root's state changes.

PRO's: Object hierarchy still doesn't require children to know parent/root.

CON's: Easy to miss a required update as the model evolves.  Children's IsFlying state could be changed by someone other than the root object.  More complex.

My leaning is to introduce the reference to the root in every descendant, but want to see if I'm missing a more elegant solution, or if I'm missing/underestimating an important consequence of that path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything simpler than your first suggestion.

The second is an opening to potential bugs, and any other solution would require additional classes that connect wings to planes.

Go with the first, and if in the future your models get too complicated, break them into additional objects. No need to worry about it now.

Answer (score 0):

One pattern that has worked very well for me is a simplified container model. Simply put, defining a simple homomorphic interface on components:

```
public interface IContained
{
    IContained Parent { get; set; }
}
```

You can write extension methods like these, to go up to any level in the hierarchy for a particular parent:

```
public IContained GetContainer(this IContained ChildObject)
{
    if (ChildObject == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return ChildObject.Parent;
}

public T GetContainer<T>(this IContained ChildObject)
{
    if (ChildObject == null)
        return null;

    ChildObject = ChildObject.Parent;

    while (ChildObject != null && !ChildObject is T) {
        ChildObject = ChildObject.Parent;
    }

    return (T)ChildObject;
}
```

To navigate down, you can define another simple interface:

```
public interface IContainedComponent
{
    IEnumerable<IContainedComponent> GetComponents();
}
```

The trick is in creating base classes and collections which set the parent property for you lazily, or enumerate the child objects. It's a fairly flexible pattern.

Comment: That's a possible mechanism for elegantly implementing Option A, but doesn't help me select between available options.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

option "A" goes against "[Loose coupling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc947917.aspx)", which really IMHO is most important principle in software architecture.

At a bare minimum your children will need to know of an interface or worse the parent itself to implement it. Which means your children code will be tied to the parent code.

Also, with MVVM knowing the parent does not mean that the INotifyPropertyChanged event will occur on your children automatically.  Which if it is a requirement means you need to have an IsFlying property on the child regardless.  If it is not a requirement, will it become one in the future?

Other options that stay on the loose coupling path may be.
having an anonomous delegate or func on the child that is set by the parent and returns the parents IsFlying property.

or when instantiating the the children, add a PropertyChanged Event on the parent that updates the child
example

```
public class Airplane
{
    WingAssembly _wing;

    protected void CreateWing()
    {
        wing = new WingAssembly();
        PropertyChanged += (s,e) => wing.IsFlying = IsFlying; 
    }
}
```